# How to check an array against a regex with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of jQuery which I'm using to identify spam submissions in a form by using a regex to check for blacklisted keywords in the user input. It works great, but it's only able to check one field. I would like it to check the input of all fields which I've added a class to.

This is what I have that's working:

```
jQuery(function($) {
 var user_input = $(":input[name=input_4]");  
 user_input.change(function() {
     var spam_check = user_input.val().search(/\b(marketing|penis enhancement|dating)\b/i); 
     if (spam_check !== -1) {
         alert("This is spam"); 
     } 
 });  
});
```

And this is the version I've modified but I'm having issues with:

```
jQuery(function($) {
 var user_input = $(".spam-check");  
 user_input.change(function() {
     var spam_check = user_input.val().search(/\b(marketing|penis enhancement|dating)\b/i); 
     if (spam_check !== -1) {
         alert("This is spam"); 
     } 
 });  
});
```

I've been trying to somehow return all the values of the array as a single string, but I'm at a loss...

Comment: $() selector returns collection. val() method returns value of first element. use $(this) selector for current element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` instead

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var user_input = $(".spam-check");
  user_input.change(function() {
    var spam_check = $(this).val().search(/\b(marketing|penis enhancement|dating)\b/i);
    if (spam_check !== -1) {
      alert("This is spam");
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the code a bit improved

```js
$(function() {
  const user_input = $(".spam-check");
  user_input.on('change', e => $(e.currentTarget).val().search(/\b(marketing|penis enhancement|dating)\b/i) !== -1 ?  alert("This is spam") : '');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! 
I have a follow up question though because it's not working for me still...

I just realized the class I was going to use for the input fields isn't being applied to the input fields directly but instead to on of its parents...
If I was to change `const user_input = $(".spam-check");` to `const user_input = $(".spam-check > input");` should that work? 
Alternatively, all these input fields have a name that starts with "input_", so I would think I could do `const user_input = $(":input[name^="input_"]");`, but I can't get it working with either of these selectors...

Comment: @MitchMcQuinn `If I was to change const user_input = $(".spam-check"); to const user_input = $(".spam-check > input"); should that work?` -- YES, `so I would think I could do const user_input = $(":input[name^="input_"]")` -- Should work

Comment: Strange, it's still not working when I try to use either of those selectors with either the modified or improved versions you posted above...

Comment: Ooh! Nevermind, I got it! I was using a double quote where it should have been single ‍♂️

Thanks again for your help! You're a real life saver ‍♂️